# "Remove Button" action on Netsuite Workflow

Tags: button, workflow, netsuite

I am trying perform a "remove button" action on Netsuite Workflow.
The remove button is related ro the print button.

After adding the action to the workflow states that I intent to hide the print button for.
I refreshed the worfklow.
the action was not taken into consideration.

for visibility : this is an internal work workflow that I can not specify more information.

PS : I checked NS community for suitenaswers and done my homework on oracle community in vain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does your workflow have any conditions on it.

Have you checked that the record is going into the workflow?